# BigQuery: How to structure multiple SQL codes into one and write data into tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have 2 SQL queries in Bigquery and I want them to run one after another. How should I build this data pipeline and automate it?

```
Select 
a,
b
INTO Table2
From Table1;
Select
a,
b
INTO Table3
FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use BigQuery DDL command to create `table2` and then use it in the next query to create `table3`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `YOUR_PROJECT.YOUR_DATASET.table2` AS
SELECT a, b FROM `YOUR_PROJECT.YOUR_DATASET.table1`;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `YOUR_PROJECT.YOUR_DATASET.table3` AS
SELECT a, b FROM `YOUR_PROJECT.YOUR_DATASET.table2`;
```

**NOTE**: Change `YOUR_PROJECT` and `YOUR_DATASET` to what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of automation needed. For example, you may create tables using multiple create table statements and then schedule them to run at a certain frequency.

A quick route to schedule queries is to use Google cloud console, select your project and open the BigQuery editor. Type in the multiple SQL statements each ending with a semicolon and use the schedule query option to schedule them.

More at:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_new_table

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

Answer (score 0):

First, probably it's better to provide your use cases first. There's a lot of automation tools that can be used. Suppose you want to make it automated you can:

1. Check whether the table already exist first, and then [create if necessary](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_a_table_only_if_the_table_doesnt_exist)
2. Do [create or replace](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#creating_or_replacing_a_table).

The 1st option usually works if you want to do update, for example you're doing daily update to your table, by keep appending the data. Second option, works if you only wants to save the latest state of your table.